# Foundation 6 dropdownmenu styling is missing

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

using foundation 6 trying to generate a dropdwon menu, have copied their example code  (from here: https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown-menu.html) but it doesn't seem to be working at all. (http://prntscr.com/o8y3kx)

I include foundation.css in the head http://prntscr.com/o8y0mm (just has a different name: addMe.css)
and include the rest of the required files in the footer http://prntscr.com/o8y1et
in the addMe.js I execute foundation http://prntscr.com/o8y1ov

the result looks like this: http://prntscr.com/o8y3vx

it seems like all the styles/js that are suppose to format the dropdown aren't included. But the version of foundation I am using is the complete one. So this doesn't seem like it's the answer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It simply seemed that there was stuff missing in my foundation.min.js downloaded, extracted and uploaded a new one and it worked like a charm